# Script não funciona

Tags: javascript

O objectivo é caso o campo esteja vazio escreva na "label" que o campo não pode estar vazio.

O objectivo do form é ir ao confirmaNovaParagem.php  enviar os dados e depois o confirmaNovaParagem reenvia o utilizador para a pagina de adicionar paragens.

O que acontece é que o script não funciona  e vai logo para o ConfirmaNovaParagem.php.

Sou iniciante em javascript desculpe qualquer erro mas óbvio.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function valida_form (){
        if(document.getElementById("adicionanomeparagem").value == ""){
            var div = document.getElementById("adicionanomeparagem");
            div.innerText = "Não pode estar vazio!"        
        }
    }
</script>
<div id="content">       
    <div id="segundofundo">
        <div id="titulo">
            <center>Adicionar Paragem</center>
        </div>
        <form name="Adicionaparagem" action="confirmaNovaParagem.php" method="post">
            <div id="fundotitulo"><br><br>
                Nome da paragem:<br><br>
                <input type="text" name="adicionanomeparagem"><br><br>

                Latitude paragem:<br><br>
                <input type="text" name="adicionalatitudeparagem"><br><br>

                Longitude paragem:<br><br>
                <input type="text" name="adicionalongitudeparagem"><br><br>

                Estado paragem: <br><br>            
                <select name="estadoparagem">
                    <option value="1">Activa</option>
                    <option value="2">Inactiva</option>
                </select><br><br>

                <div id="posicaobotao">
                    <input class="botao" value="Adicionar"  onclick="valida_form ()" type="submit" >
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vou listar o que eu achei no seu arquivo, que pode estar te causando problemas.

1. O seu html não está completamente formado. Existe um fechamento de `div` extra antes do fechamento do `form`.
2. A sua função não continha um retorno, sendo assim, toda vez que você clicava no botão, a ação de submit era executada.
3. O seu onclick estava chamando a função, mas não estava tratando o retorno, quando se coloca, `onclick="return valida_form()"`, ele executa a função e caso o retorno seja falso, o submit não é executado. Caso o retorno seja verdadeiro, o submit é executado.
4. Nessa linha `document.getElementById("adicionanomeparagem").value == ""` você está tentando pegar o elemento pelo id, porém os seus inputs não possuem id e sim name. Adicione a propriedade id para o input desejado.
5. Nessa linha `var div = document.getElementById("adicionanomeparagem");` você estava tentando pegar uma "div" que possui o mesmo id do seu input. O que não seria o correto, pois o id é unico, ou seja, somente um elemento no dom, pode possuir aquele id.

Aqui está um boa [referência](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp) de como fazer validação de formulários.

Abaixo seque o meu código com apenas algumas modificações, nada sofisticado, do que eu faria no seu código.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function valida_form (){            
        if(document.getElementById("adicionanomeparagem").value == ""){
            var div = document.getElementById("validacaonomeparagem");
            div.innerText = "Não pode estar vazio!"
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
<div id="content">       
    <div id="segundofundo">
        <div id="titulo">
            <center>Adicionar Paragem</center>
        </div>
        <form name="Adicionaparagem" action="confirmaNovaParagem.php" method="post">
            <div id="fundotitulo"><br><br>
                Nome da paragem:<br><br>
                <input id="adicionanomeparagem" name="adicionanomeparagem" type="text"><br><br>
                <div id="validacaonomeparagem"></div>

                Latitude paragem:<br><br>
                <input type="text" name="adicionalatitudeparagem"><br><br>

                Longitude paragem:<br><br>
                <input type="text" name="adicionalongitudeparagem"><br><br>

                Estado paragem: <br><br>            
                <select name="estadoparagem">
                    <option value="1">Activa</option>
                    <option value="2">Inactiva</option>
                </select><br><br>

                <div id="posicaobotao">
                    <input class="botao" value="Adicionar"  onclick="return valida_form ()" type="submit" >
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tens de parar o envio da form com `event.preventDefault()`, isso impede o `button` de agir como esperado. Depois fazes a verificação e caso seja válida corres `form.submit();`

Dá uma olhada a este exemplo, depois de clicares no `enviar` ele espera 5 segundos e envia a form, portanto interrompendo o que é esperado.

```js
var button = document.querySelector('button');
var form = document.querySelector('form');
button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(function() {
        form.submit();
    }, 5000);
});
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ov57u1zp/

---

No teu caso o código teria de ser:

```
<input class="botao" value="Adicionar"  onclick="valida_form(event)" type="submit" >
```

e na função:

```
function valida_form (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // resto da lógica de validação
    // ...
    // e depois, se tudo estiver certo:
    document.querySelector('form[name="Adicionaparagem"]').submit();
```